# zooming android image about centre of the image

Tags: android

I have an android application that needs to zoom an image about centre. i implemented the code
                      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                      matrix.setScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                      imView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                      imView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                     imView.invalidate(); 
But i get the zooming about top left of the imView(imageView). i need to make it about centre. anybody please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the four-argument version of `setScale` that takes a pivot point.